# Mootools .slide hide and show problem

Tags: mootools

my intention was to make  some kind of produkt overview for my website. so i have  2  div container that i wanted  to slide in and of by using mootools. to be more exactly when the first div  slides out  the  second should  slide in and vice  versa. BUT the last part doesnt work. i manage to slide of  one  but  the other doesnt come  back. ( hope this is understandable.

here is the code:

```
var redo = new Request.HTML(
{
    url: 'ajax/cdvet.php',
    update: artikel,
    encoding: 'utf-8',
     onComplete: function(response){
        if(hund != null)
          {
          hund.slide('hide');
          $('clist_tier_Hund').addEvent( 'click', function(e)
            {
               hund.toggle();
             artikel.toggle();             
            }); 
          }
      artikel.slide('in');
      }
});
```

hope anyone  can help me  :)

Comment: Care to create a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with this example?

Comment: its live  here:   http://www.rudolfapotheke.de/produktkatalog.php    look under  the  doggy  :)

Answer (score 2):

`Fx.Slide` is made to animate one object at a time. It wasn't made to carousel multiple elements.

You can however use `Fx.Elements` to animate your different carousel panes... Or, if you prefer simplicity, you can use `Fx.Scroll.Carousel` available in the [Mootools Forge](http://mootools.net/forge/p/fx_scroll_carousel).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QpBdv/)

Comment: nice thing this demo - but  seems  far  to complex  for  what i need.  i will look into  fx.elements  pitty  the documentation on mootools website  is somewhat cryptical for me...

Comment: @Dimitar: No, `Fx.Scroll.Carousel` was made by Ryan Florence and is available in the [Mootools Forge](http://mootools.net/forge/p/fx_scroll_carousel).

Comment: ah, good old rpflo - was going to say, bit much for a demo unless you planned to recycle it and use it yourself :)

Comment: @Dimitar: The demo facilities @MooForge are a bit broken right now, so I had to move it to jsFiddle.